# javascript event not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown for number of travelers.

When I change the value *(say select 2)*, it displays some more dropdowns (in this case 2 dropdowns) for entering the age of travelers.

This is existing functionality. Now I have created another dropdown, here I have written an `onChange` function that sets the value of travelers:

```
document.getElementById("travellers").value="1";
```

I want the additional dropdowns for the age to appear on their own which does not happen.

How can I effect this to happen using jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Please show what have you tried?

Comment: @kevinabelita An edit that makes a few things italics and once sentence bold? Are you serious? Talk about meaningless edits.

Comment: @Tomalak, I wonder who has approved that edit. Edit approval on SO should be revised

Comment: when i was formatting the question, it was still on a single paragraph, I did not know that it was already formatted after i clicked edit, so that change was small

Comment: @kevinabelita Curious you hit *exactly* the same paragraph format as the edit before you. Also, if you see the "this has been edited" popup while you're editing yourself, you're supposed to refresh instead of blindly overwriting a previous edit.

Comment: yeah i forgot the refresh on the popup my bad thank you for the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modifies value programatically event will not fire. You need to trigger event.

*Using vanilla JS*

```
var select = document.getElementById("travellers");
//fire the event
if("createEvent" in document) { //NON IE browsers
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    select.dispatchEvent(evt);
} else { //IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    select.fireEvent("onchange", evt);
}
```

As you have tagged your question with jQuery you can use [**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$("#travellers").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Since this question is also tagged with jQuery, I'd suggest adding the jQuery equivalent to your answer.

Comment: @Satpal now i understand that i have just changed the value and not triggered the event. This one liner works like magic. Thanks.

Comment: @Satpal when i use $("#travellers").trigger("change"); today , i get error, "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function".